# Why is the map undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am a novice at redux and i am trying to incorporate it in my code so the state can be managed more easily. I am trying to map through an array in my state but it is throwing the error below:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

this is the reducer for redux

```
const initialState = {
    workoutlist: [
        {
            id: uuid.v4(),
            name: 'Leg Day',
            date: '08-09-2019',
            duration: "60",
            exerciselist: [
                {
                    id: uuid.v4(),
                    exerciseName: 'Squats',
                    numberOfSets: "3",
                    reps: "12",
                    weight: "135",
                },
                {
                    id: uuid.v4(),
                    exerciseName: 'Leg press',
                    numberOfSets: "3",
                    reps: "10",
                    weight: "150",
                },
                {
                    id: uuid.v4(),
                    exerciseName: 'Lunges',
                    numberOfSets: "4",
                    reps: "12",
                    weight: "0",
                },
            ],
            selected: false,
        },
        {
            id: uuid.v4(),
            name: 'Running',
            date: '08-11-2019',
            duration: "40",
            exerciselist: [],
            selected: false,

        },
    ],
    disabled: true,
    page: 1,
}

const workoutList = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {

        // Returns whether the panel is selected or not 
        // and enables Start Workout button if only 1 is selected
        case 'SELECT_PANEL':
            state = {
                workoutlist: state.workoutlist.map(workout => {
                    if (workout.id === action.id) {
                        workout.selected = !workout.selected
                    }
                    return workout;
                })
            }
            var count = 0;
            state.workoutlist.map((workout) => {
                if (workout.selected === true) {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
                return count;
            })
            if (count !== 1) {
                state = {
                    ...state,
                    disabled: true
                }
            } else {
                state = {
                    ...state,
                    disabled: false
                }
            }
            return state;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

this is the component that where the error is being thrown.

```
export default function WorkoutItem() {
    const handleSelectedPanel = useSelector(state => state.workoutList);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { name, date, duration, exerciselist } = handleSelectedPanel;
    return (
        <ExpansionPanel style={styles.panel} onChange={() => dispatch(selectPanel())}>
            <ExpansionPanelSummary>
                <Typography variant="button" style={styles.header}>
                    {name}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="button" style={styles.header}>
                    {date}
                </Typography>
                <Typography align="right" style={styles.header}>
                    ~{duration} mins
                    </Typography>
            </ExpansionPanelSummary>
            <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                <Table size="medium" style={styles.table}>
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell padding="none" >Name</TableCell>
                            <TableCell padding="none" align="right"># of sets</TableCell>
                            <TableCell padding="none" align="right">average reps</TableCell>
                            <TableCell padding="none" align="right">weight</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {exerciselist.map((exercise) => (
                            <ExerciseList
                                key={exercise.id}
                                exercise={exercise}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
                <ExpansionPanelActions disableSpacing style={styles.actionButton}>
                    <EditWorkoutItem
                        workout={this.props.workout}
                        handleEditChange={this.props.handleEditChange}
                    />
                </ExpansionPanelActions>
            </ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
    )
}
```

It is supposed to show a list of panels that can be expanded to show the contents but it throws an error saying the exerciselist is undefined in my state apparently.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean `const exerciselist = useSelector(state => state.workoutList);`?

Comment: It appears to be a typo, not a redux/react issue

Comment: There's also asome fundamental mistakes with your function component. It won't have a `this`, so you can't access `this.props.handleEditChange `. You'll need to add props like `function WorkoutItem(props)`

Comment: Where is your `useSelector `?

Comment: What does `console.log(handleSelectedPanel)` gives you?

Comment: My useSelector is in the second line of WorkoutItem.. Also, console.log(handleSelectedPanel) returns the initialState twice follow by the undefined map error and repeats that pattern 3 times.

Comment: @KaseyKaufmann can your add a codeSandbox link?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to access the first item or `workoutList` ?. From your code `handleSelectedPanel` seams to be an array not an object. Is your destructuring correct?. Where is your `useSelector`?. What does `console.log(handleSelectedPanel)` gives you? Try

```
const { name, date, duration, exerciselist } = handleSelectedPanel[0];
```

or

```
const handleSelectedPanel = useSelector(state => state.workoutList[0]);
```